# How to post values in XML format from Magento

Tags: xml, magento, soap, payment-gateway

I'm trying to create a custom payment gateway the redirects to Chase paymentech DPP. I have the module working up until I reach the gateway when I receieve this error message:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns="urn:ws.paymentech.net/PaymentechGateway">
<SOAP-ENV:Body id="_0">
<SOAP-ENV:Fault SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:VersionMismatch</faultcode>
<faultstring>SOAP version mismatch or invalid SOAP message</faultstring>
<SOAP-ENV:Code/>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'm not sure if its to do with formatting the form to post in the correct format i.e XML so would like to ask for some advice on how to post values in the correct format

This is my form named redirect.phtml which redirects to the payment gateway.

```
<?php 
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $orderIncrementId = $session->getLastRealOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
    $billingaddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
    $shippingaddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
    $currencyDesc = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    $totals = number_format($order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.', ''); 
    $address = $billingaddress->getStreet();
    $address1 = $shippingaddress->getStreet();
    $data = array(
    'api_username' => trim(Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/redirect/api_username')),
    'api_password' => trim(Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/redirect/api_password')),
    'Merchant_ID' => trim(Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/redirect/Merchant_ID')),
    'Terminal_ID' => trim(Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/redirect/Terminal_ID')),
    'BIN_Number' => trim(Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/redirect/BIN_Number')),
    'Amount' => $totals,
    'billing_cust_name' =>$order->getCustomerFirstname(), 
    'billing_last_name'=>$order->getCustomerLastname(),
    'billing_cust_tel_No' => $billingaddress->getTelephone(),
    'billing_cust_email'=>$order->getCustomerEmail(),
    'billing_cust_address'=>$address[0] . ' '.$address[1],
    'billing_cust_city'=>$billingaddress->getCity(),
    'billing_cust_country'=>$billingaddress->getCountryId(),
    'billing_cust_state'=>$billingaddress->getRegion(),
    'billing_cust_zip' =>$billingaddress->getPostcode(),
    'delivery_cust_name' =>$shippingaddress->getCustomerFirstname(),
    'delivery_last_name'=>$shippingaddress->getCustomerLastname(),
    'delivery_cust_tel_No' => $shippingaddress->getTelephone(),
    'delivery_cust_email'=>$shippingaddress->getCustomerEmail(),
    'delivery_cust_address'=>$address1[0] . ' '.$address1[1],
    'delivery_cust_city'=>$shippingaddress->getCity(),
    'delivery_cust_country'=>$shippingaddress->getCountryId(),
    'delivery_cust_state'=>$shippingaddress->getRegion(),
    'delivery_cust_zip' =>$shippingaddress->getPostcode(),
    'Order_Id' => $order->getIncrementId(),
    'TxnType' => 'A',
    'actionID' => 'TXN',
    'Currency' => 'GBP',
    );

?>
<form action="https://wsvar.paymentech.net/PaymentechGateway" method="post" id="chase">
    <?php foreach($data as $key => $value): ?>
        <input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $key?>' value='<?php echo $value;?>' />
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large" value='Complete my order!'/> 
</form>
<?php echo $this->__('If Page Doesn\'t Redirect In 5 Sectonds, Please press Buy button');?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc () {
    var frm = document.getElementById("chase");
    frm.submit();
    }
    window.onload = myfunc;
</script>
```

Standard.php

```
<?php
class Custom_Gateway_Model_Standard extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract {
    protected $_code = 'chase';
    protected $_isInitializeNeeded      = true;
    protected $_canUseInternal          = true;
    protected $_canUseForMultishipping  = false;

    public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() {
    return Mage::getUrl('chase/payment/redirect', array('_secure' => true));
    }

    //create xml and send info to gateway
    private function callApi(Varien_Object $payment, $amount,$type){

    //call your authorize api here, incase of error throw exception.
    //only example code written below to show flow of code

    $order = $payment->getOrder();
    $types = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getCcTypes();
    if (isset($types[$payment->getCcType()])) {
    $type = $types[$payment->getCcType()];
    }
    $billingaddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
    $totals = number_format($amount, 2, '.', '');
    $orderId = $order->getIncrementId();
    $currencyDesc = $order->getBaseCurrencyCode();

    $url = $this->getConfigData('gateway_url');
    $fields = array(
            'api_username'=> $this->getConfigData('api_username'),
            'api_password'=> $this->getConfigData('api_password'),
            'Merchant_ID'=> $this->getConfigData('Merchant_ID'),
            'Terminal_ID'=> $this->getConfigData('Terminal_ID'),
            'BIN_Number'=> $this->getConfigData('BIN_Number'),
            'customer_firstname'=> $billingaddress->getData('firstname'),
            'customer_lastname'=> $billingaddress->getData('lastname'),
            'customer_phone'=> $billingaddress->getData('telephone'),
            'customer_email'=> $billingaddress->getData('email'),
            'customer_ipaddress'=> $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            'bill_firstname'=> $billingaddress->getData('firstname'),
            'bill_lastname'=> $billingaddress->getData('lastname'),
            'Bill_address1'=> $billingaddress->getData('street'),
            'bill_city'=> $billingaddress->getData('city'),
            'bill_country'=> $billingaddress->getData('country_id'),
            'bill_state'=> $billingaddress->getData('region'),
            'bill_zip'=> $billingaddress->getData('postcode'),
            'customer_cc_expmo'=> $payment->getCcExpMonth(),
            'customer_cc_expyr'=> $payment->getCcExpYear(),
            'customer_cc_number'=> $payment->getCcNumber(),
            'customer_cc_type'=> strtoupper($type),
            'customer_cc_cvc'=> $payment->getCcCid(),
            'merchant_ref_number'=> $order->getIncrementId(),
            'currencydesc'=>$currencyDesc,
            'amount'=>$totals
    );

    $fields_string="";
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    $fields_string = substr($fields_string,0,-1);
    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION ,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER ,0); // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,1); // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120); // Timeout on connect (2 minutes)
    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return array('status'=>1,'transaction_id' => time() , 'fraud' => rand(0,1));
  }
}
?>
```

Authorize.php

```
 protected function _getTransactionDetails($transactionId)
    {
        $requestBody = sprintf(
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
            . '<getTransactionDetailsRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">'
            . '<merchantAuthentication><name>%s</name><transactionKey>%s</transactionKey></merchantAuthentication>'
            . '<transId>%s</transId>'
            . '</getTransactionDetailsRequest>',
            $this->getConfigData('login'),
            $this->getConfigData('trans_key'),
            $transactionId
        );

        $client = new Varien_Http_Client();
        $uri = $this->getConfigData('cgi_url_td');
        $client->setUri($uri ? $uri : self::CGI_URL_TD);
        $client->setConfig(array('timeout'=>45));
        $client->setHeaders(array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
        $client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
        $client->setRawData($requestBody);

        $debugData = array('request' => $requestBody);

        try {
            $responseBody = $client->request()->getBody();
            $debugData['result'] = $responseBody;
            $this->_debug($debugData);
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $responseXmlDocument = new Varien_Simplexml_Element($responseBody);
            libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('paygate')->__('Payment updating error.'));
        }

        $response = new Varien_Object;
        $response
            ->setResponseCode((string)$responseXmlDocument->transaction->responseCode)
            ->setResponseReasonCode((string)$responseXmlDocument->transaction->responseReasonCode)
            ->setTransactionStatus((string)$responseXmlDocument->transaction->transactionStatus)
        ;
        return $response;
    }



Thanks in advance
```

Comment: @John apologies, I've edited the question so hopefully it is much more clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge you should only use one of these method (and not both), because they represent two different type of gateway.

```
public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() {
return Mage::getUrl('chase/payment/redirect', array('_secure' => true));
}

//create xml and send info to gateway
private function callApi(Varien_Object $payment, $amount,$type){
```

What I would recommend is start over (i am not sure what 'Standard.php' and 'Authorize.php' does)  using this example http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method-api-based and make changes to `callApi`

Also take a look of

`protected function _postRequest(Varien_Object $request)`

`protected function _buildRequest(Varien_Object $payment)`

In

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, could you show me how to incorprate this into my existing file please?

Comment: Thankyou, I had attempted to use the API method but I wasn't able to get the correct form to show up in the checkout page...?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I am actually trying to implement a different method whereby users are redirected to the gateway payment page instead of entering credit card details on our site!?!?